# How to access elements in the DOM?

Tags: xml, dom, web

So I have this xml file:

```
<root>
   <node>
      <name>One</name>
      <val>1</val>
   </node>
   <node>
      <name>Two</name>
      <val>2</val>
   </node>
   <node>
      <name>Three</name>
      <val>3</val>
   </node>
</root>
```

So from what I understand, in order to access all the nodes I need to get a list of nodes by using getElementsByName("node");

Now, once I have gotten that list, how do I do about accessing all the child elements? I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.

Basically I need to loop through all the node elements and for each one I need to take out the name and value because I am using those to call another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, you can use the DOM Traversal API: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/traversal.html

In java, it woul be something like this:

```
Document doc = ...;
NodeIterator i = ((DocumentTraversal) doc).createNodeIterator(doc,
NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, false);
Element e = null;
while ((e = (Element) i.nextNode()) != null) {
   System.out.println(e.getTagName());
}
```

JavaScript should have something similar if the traversal API is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If x is a node object then ,  You can use the properties x.childNodes  which will give you the list of all the child elements of Node x.
And then you can access y.nodeValue  where y is the child node to get the value of the node.

Comment: So if I get a list of nodes using x.childNodes, and then each one of those nodes has two fields in it. How would I access field 1 and field 2 directly? Can I use getElementByName?

Comment: x.childNodes will give you the nodelist i.e                           NodeList nl1 = x.getChildNodes();              n11.item(0) will give you the name and nl1.item(1) will give you value of that node.

Comment: You should refer DOM API to do that. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes()